# LogicApp/JavaScript - Split JSON data to multiple objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, json, azure-logic-apps

I have below JSON data coming from source system into my Logic App:

```
[
   {
      "project":"abc",
      "assignees":"123,456"
   },
   {
      "project":"xyz",
      "assignees":"123,468"
   }
]
```

I want to split the "assignees", create arrays within objects, and produce below final output:

```
[
   {
      "metadata":{
         "type":"project"
      },
      "name":"Project ABC",
      "assignee":[
         {
            "metadata":{
               "type":"assignment"
            },
            "employeeId":"123"
         },
         {
            "metadata":{
               "type":"assignment"
            },
            "employeeId":"123"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "metadata":{
         "type":"project"
      },
      "name":"Project ABC",
      "assignee":[
         {
            "metadata":{
               "type":"assignment"
            },
            "employeeId":"123"
         },
         {
            "metadata":{
               "type":"assignment"
            },
            "employeeId":"468"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Can this be achieved in Logic App only? If not, can this be achieved using inline JavaScript code and how?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/9078341)

Comment: @RandyCasburn Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initialize a variable named `source` to store same data source with yours.

[image]

And here provide a sample of inline javascript code for your reference:

```
var source = workflowContext.actions.Initialize_variable.inputs.variables[0].value;

var result = [];

source.forEach(sItem=>{
    var resultItem = {
        "metadata":{
         "type":"project"
        },
        "name":"Project " + sItem.project.toUpperCase()
    }

    var assignee = [];
    var assigneesSplit = sItem.assignees.split(",");
    
    assigneesSplit.forEach(item=>{
        var assigneItem = {
            "metadata":{
               "type":"assignment"
            },
            "employeeId":item
        }
        assignee.push(assigneItem);
    });
    resultItem.assignee = assignee;
    
    result.push(resultItem);
});

return result;
```

After running the logic app, we can get the result data like:

```
[
  {
    "metadata": {
      "type": "project"
    },
    "name": "Project ABC",
    "assignee": [
      {
        "metadata": {
          "type": "assignment"
        },
        "employeeId": "123"
      },
      {
        "metadata": {
          "type": "assignment"
        },
        "employeeId": "456"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "metadata": {
      "type": "project"
    },
    "name": "Project XYZ",
    "assignee": [
      {
        "metadata": {
          "type": "assignment"
        },
        "employeeId": "123"
      },
      {
        "metadata": {
          "type": "assignment"
        },
        "employeeId": "468"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It seems there are some mistakes in your expected data sample(such as the second project name and the second `employeeId` in first `assignee` field). If they are not typo, please let me know, I will modify my js inline code to implement your expected json data.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about LogicApp or how it works, but if all you want is javascript code that can make this transformation you can do something like this:

```
const src=[
   {
      "project":"abc",
      "assignees":"123,456"
   },
   {
      "project":"xyz",
      "assignees":"123,468"
   }
]
const transformed=src.map(entry=>({
                            "metadata":{type:"project"},
                            name:"Project "+entry.project.toUpperCase(),
                            assignee:entry.assignees.split(",").map(assignee=>({
                                                            metadata:{type:"assignment"},
                                                            emplyeeId:assignee
                                                            }))
                            }))
```